# Excel Formula to subtract two dates

Tags: excel

I have the attached formula and it's almost perfect, however when it hits business day 3 it adds a month when it should stay the same until day 4. The formula needs to subtract the end date minus the start date and to not recognize a new month until accounting day 4 of a new month. Any help is appreciatedm below is the formula.

```
=(MONTH(C2)+YEAR(C2)*12)-(MONTH(D2)+YEAR(D2)*12) +
  (NETWORKDAYS(DATE(YEAR(C2),MONTH(C2),1),C2)>3) -
  (NETWORKDAYS(DATE(YEAR(D2),MONTH(D2),1),D2)>3)
```

here the input data:

| End Date | Start Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2/2/2022 | 3/6/2018 |
| 8/5/2022 | 3/20/2018 |
| 6/21/2022 | 6/10/2020 |
| 8/3/2022 | 6/10/2020 |
| 8/11/2022 | 6/10/2020 |
| 4/18/2022 | 11/2/2020 |
| 4/23/2022 | 11/6/2020 |
| 7/2/2022 | 11/2/2020 |
| 7/2/2022 | 11/2/2020 |
| 8/13/2022 | 11/2/2020 |
| 9/7/2022 | 11/2/2020 |
| 8/3/2022 | 7/1/2022 |
| 9/1/2022 | 5/1/2022 |

[Excel with Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV2xh.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a different approach. In `C2` the following formula and then extend it down:

```
=IF(MONTH(A2)=MONTH(WORKDAY(A2,-4)), 
   DATEDIF(B2,A2,"M"), DATEDIF(B2,A2,"M")-1)
```

or using `LET` to avoid repetition:

```
=LET(months, DATEDIF(B2,A2,"M"), IF(MONTH(A2)=MONTH(WORKDAY(A2,-4)), months, months-1))
```

`DATEDIF` can calculate the number of complete months between two dates via second input argument: `unit` in months (`M`). The logic to exclude the last month if the end date hasn't reached the fourth business day is via the following condition:

```
MONTH(A2)=MONTH(WORKDAY(A2,-4)
```

If the corresponding months are not the same, the accounting months hasn't started yet. `WORDAY` with the second input argument `-4` returns the date of the previous fourth business day.

For example for the end date: `2/2/2022` (Feb, 2nd, 2022) was a Wednesday.   We are looking for the fourth business day before that date is `1/27/2022` which corresponds to the previous month so we need to subtract one month.

Here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

**Notes**:

1. The **highlighted** columns are just for testing purposes
2. The input data needs to be of `DATE` type, not a text representation of a date. You can check that formatting the date as General and it shows a positive number where January 1, 1900 is serial number `1`.